# Edit Storyboard's XML using code

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm working with Xcode and Swift 3 and I'm trying to modify XML of a TableView Scene programmatically.

Basically I have two scene, both tableview scene. The first one (scene A) is a list of request to web server. The second one (scene B) is a list of object with some attribute to display in different way.

What I want is that when I click, for example, on an item of a list in scene A I receive, from the server, a block of XML with the layout of the prototype cell for the scene B and I would like to put this block in my storyboard XML code.

I don't know if this is possible and what I should look for.